# DBSCAN error with cosine metric in python

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, data-mining, cosine-similarity, dbscan

I was trying to use DBSCAN algorithm from scikit-learn library with cosine metric but was stuck with the error.
The line of code is

```
db = DBSCAN(eps=1, min_samples=2, metric='cosine').fit(X)
```

where  `X` is a `csr_matrix`. The error is the following:

> Metric 'cosine' not valid for algorithm 'auto',

though the documentation says that it is possible to use this metric.
I tried to use option `algorithm='kd_tree'` and `'ball_tree'` but got the same. However, there is no error if I use `euclidean` or, say, `l1` metric.

The matrix `X` is large, so I can't use a precomputed matrix of pairwise distances.

I use `python 2.7.6` and `scikit-learn 0.16.1`.
My dataset doesn't have a full row of zeros, so cosine metric is well-defined.

Comment: This is arguably a bug in sklearn, frankly. Cosine similarity isn't a metric. It doesn't obey the triangle inequality, which is why it won't work with a KDTree and you have no choice but to brute force it. All of which raises the question of why when you set algorithm to 'auto,' it attempts to use a method it should know it can't use.

Comment: @AdamAcosta: If I understand correctly, you're arguing that the `'auto'` `algorithm`-keyword should use `'brute'` rather than try and fail using `'ball_tree'` ? (I'd agree.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The indexes in sklearn (probably - this may change with new versions) cannot accelerate cosine.

Try `algorithm='brute'`.

For a list of metrics that your version of sklearn can accelerate, see the supported metrics of the ball tree:

```
from sklearn.neighbors.ball_tree import BallTree
print(BallTree.valid_metrics)
```

Comment: Thanks! Now it works. Firstly, it gave me an error because I used `np.float32` instead of `np.double` for my dataset.  I suppose that DBSCAN requires such precision for the cosine metric since the latter has a small range (between 0 and 1).

Comment: That should not be necessary in general, but the sklearn implementation may have such limitations.

Comment: As of today (October 2019) the 'brute' algorithm does not work, but the 'generic' one does. As noted before, the .fit method needs double precision

Answer (score 10):

If you want a normalized distance like the cosine distance, you can also normalize your vectors first and then use the euclidean metric. Notice that for two normalized vectors u and v the euclidean distance is equal to sqrt(2-2*cos(u, v)) ([see this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146221/is-cosine-similarity-identical-to-l2-normalized-euclidean-distance))

You can hence do something like:

```
Xnorm = np.linalg.norm(X,axis = 1)
Xnormed = np.divide(X,Xnorm.reshape(Xnorm.shape[0],1))
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.5, min_samples=2, metric='euclidean').fit(Xnormed)
```

The distances will lie in [0,2] so make sure you adjust your parameters accordingly.

Comment: Could you expand a little bit more on why the DBSCAN algorithm with euclidian-distance-on-normalised-vectors would yield the same result as with straightforwardly-cosine distance, if that is the case ? In particular, what's with the squaring/square-root, and does it matter that cosine really measures *similarity* and not distance (the distance is `1-cos(.;.)`)

Comment: For instance, if you know that `eps` should be set to `x` with cosine distance, then it should be set to `sqrt(x)` when using DBSCAN with `euclid`. And, if such is the data, is the sklearn indexing accomplishing its fastening purpose all right ?