# ValueError: Metric 'cosine' not valid for algorithm 'ball_tree' when using sklearn TSNE

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Package versions:

numpy: 1.13.3

sklearn: 0.19.0

scipy: 0.19.1

I have a dense matrix `svd_matrix`

```
svd_matrix.shape
>>> (30000,50)
```

I want to train this on the scikit TSNE implementation using 'cosine' as the metric

```
tsne = sklearn.manifold.TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=0, metric='cosine')
matrix_2d = tsne.fit_transform(svd_matrix)
>>> ValueError: Metric 'cosine' not valid for algorithm 'ball_tree'
```

However I get the error above. I was training this model last week and it worked fine, but I have updated my package versions in the meantime, but I don't think this would cause an issue? Anyway, package versions are above.

`algorithm` isn't an argument for `manifold.TSNE`, so I can't give `'brute'` as an argument as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745541/dbscan-error-with-cosine-metric-in-python)

Can anyone suggest what is going wrong here and how I can fix this? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code of TSNE (0.19!!!) seems to use BallTree in [every case](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a/sklearn/manifold/t_sne.py#L714) (but the precomputed one):

```
neighbors_method = 'ball_tree'
if (self.metric == 'precomputed'):
    neighbors_method = 'brute'
knn = NearestNeighbors(algorithm=neighbors_method, n_neighbors=k,
                               metric=self.metric)
```

Now what metrics are allowed within BallTree:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
BallTree.valid_metrics
# ['seuclidean', 'hamming', 'dice', 'jaccard', 'matching', 'russellrao', 
  'euclidean', 'kulsinski', 'wminkowski', 'chebyshev', 'mahalanobis',
  'sokalmichener', 'rogerstanimoto', 'infinity', 'p', 'canberra',
  'haversine', 'sokalsneath', 'l1', 'minkowski', 'pyfunc', 'l2',
  'cityblock', 'braycurtis', 'manhattan']
```

TSNE's code-base [is quite active](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commits/ef5cb84a805efbe4bb06516670a9b8c690992bd7/sklearn/manifold/t_sne.py) and there were probably some heavy changes describing your observation and also the fact, that it's not checking the metric before going to work.

[This pull-request](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/1701fcf553cda6e0aa7d1dc690ed00b6ad35615c) seems to add support for `cosine` metric, by not using BallTree in this case! As this seems to be merged, i think it would work if you install sklearn from the current master-branch!

**Edit: it actually works (as expected) in master-branch!**

The following, which makes not much sense (just a demo), runs without any errors when installing sklearn from the current master-branch (`e049b1d35fba9fa688d81a6511be38a73ae824cc`; 17.10.2017).

```
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=10, centers=3, n_features=2,
              random_state=0)

tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=0, metric='cosine')
matrix_2d = tsne.fit_transform(X)
# OK!
```

Comment: Thanks @sascha... although that still didn't seem to work even after install ing from the master branch and building it. Hopefully this get's addressed in the next version update. I can't understand why they would get rid of it?

Comment: Probably not because they want to, but more as a side-effect of tough design-decisions (and ongoing development). I think there might be a switch from dense to sparse-matrices. This alone can be deadly for a lot of stuff (especially metrics destroying sparsity; but that's just an example not necessarily true here).

Comment: @killerT2333 Just fired up my virtual-machine. Your task (see my code) actually works when using sklearn from master-branch!

Comment: I had this problem using version 0.19.0, it is fixed after an upgrade to 0.19.1.