# ValueError: Metric 'cosine' not valid. Use sorted(sklearn.neighbors.VALID_METRICS['ball_tree'])

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn, nearest-neighbor

I'm trying to use cosine metric with Ball_tree algorithm since my data is of high dimensions. e.g.

```
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=2,algorithm='ball_tree',metric='cosine').fit(data_seed)
```

However i get the following error:

```
ValueError: Metric 'cosine' not valid. Use sorted(sklearn.neighbors.VALID_METRICS['ball_tree']) to get valid options. Metric can also be a callable function.
```

I don't understand why i cannot use cosine similarity with ball tree?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46791191/valueerror-metric-cosine-not-valid-for-algorithm-ball-tree-when-using-sklea

Comment: I'm asking why i cannot use cosine with balltree. I know it states it's incompatible

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, possible regression?

Answer (score 0):

check valid matrics sklearn.neighbors.VALID_METRICS['ball_tree'])
and use instead of cosine