# Fixed RAM DBSCAN or another clustering algorithm without predefined number of clusters?

Tags: python, optimization, cluster-analysis, gensim

I want to cluster 3.5M 300-dimensional word2vec vectors from my custom gensim model to determine whether I can use those clustering to find topic-related words. It is not the same as `model.most_similar_...`, as I hope to attach quite distant, but still related words.

The overall size of the model (after normalization of vectors, i.e. `model.init_sims(replace=True)`) in memory is 4GB:

```
words = sorted(model.wv.vocab.keys())
vectors = np.array([model.wv[w] for w in words]) 
sys.getsizeof(vectors)
4456416112
```

I tried both scikit's DBSCAN and some other implementations from GitHub, but they seem to consume more and more RAM during processing and crash with `std::bad_alloc` after some time. I have 32 GB of RAM and 130GB swap.

Metric is euclidean, [I convert my cosine distance threshold cos=0.48 as eps=sqrt(2-2*0.48)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745541/dbscan-error-with-cosine-metric-in-python/40368885#40368885), so all the optimizations should be applied.

The problem is that I don't know the number of clusters and want to determine them by setting the threshold for closely related words (let it be `cos<0.48` or `d_l2 < sqrt(2-2*0.48)`). DBSCAN seems working on small subsets, but I can't pass the computation on the full data.

Is there any algorithm or workaround in Python which can help with that?

EDIT: Distance matrix seem to be for a size(float)=4bytes: 3.5M*3.5M*4/1024(KB)/1024(MB)/1024(GB)/1024(TB) = 44.5 TB, so it's impossible to precompute it.

EDIT2: Currently trying ELKI, but cannot make it to cluster data on toy subset properly.

Comment: sklearn's DBSCAN is, unfortunately, memory intensive. If you choose a too large threshold, it needs O(n²) memory. Usual implementations of DBSCAN should only use O(n) memory. However, with 300 dimensional vectors, choosing the epsilon parameter for DBSCAN *will* be difficult with any implementation. Maybe that is where your problem is, because I find ELKI to be easy to use (make sure to add an index for large data, it does not do this automatically!)

Comment: What does not "properly" work in ELKI? Can you be more precise?

Comment: @ErichSchubert Sorry, everything seems working correctly today, perhaps I did something wrong yesterday.

Comment: Thanks @Anony-Mousse, I have already achieved correct results on toy dataset and will try to process full data in ELKI and write here the results